# show and alert on bootstrap modal window

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

We are using bootstrap 3.0 for creating a modal and want to reconfirm when use pushes the submit button by using an alert window or any popup window.

But the same doesn't seem to be working ok.

```
<div class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal title</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>One fine body&hellip;</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="savebutton">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
  </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div><!-- /.modal -->

$('#savebutton').on('click', function(e){

e.preventDefault();

//This is where we would like to add an alert or confirmation of some sort to ask user if they really want to save the results and if they say yes..submit it and if they say No take them back to the popup
}   
});
```

Is there a way to do the same??

Comment: sorry wanted to check quickly..let em edit it

Comment: So, you simply need to show the modal in the current `#savebutton` click event, then add a new ID/Class to the **Save button of the modal** (`id="saveConfirm"` for example), and add a new click event to the `#saveConfirm` element that trigger the actual save after the user has click the button

Comment: [I have just noticed](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals) that _Multiple open modals not supported_, so when the user click in the `#savebutton` element, you should trigger a click event from the code that will close the current modal (`$(this).prev().click()` - This, when called from within the `'#savebutton'` click callback,  will close the modal from the code by clicking the the close button)

Comment: yeah that's what my problem is and wanted to see if there is a way to handle it manually...i don't want to close my current modal window..as you might want to just cancel and go back at it

Comment: Overlapping modals http://www.bootply.com/3WVKSSFNKN .... or individual modals http://www.bootply.com/yuj3IoX45r ... It's just handle on the right way Id's and data-attributes

Comment: @DaniP That's a great demo, so why not post it as an answer?

Comment: wasn't clear to me the question @AlonEitan but will post it after see the previous comment of OP

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you need is to handle two different modals and use the `data-toggle` properties on the buttons to show/hide the one you want:

So have two modasl one `#mod` and after `#confirm`, then on the first one to trigger the second use on the button:

> data-toggle="modal" data-target="#confirm"

And on the `confirm` modal to came back use on the no button:

> data-dismiss="modal" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#mod"

---

***Some Examples***

**<sub>With Overlapping Modals</sub>**

```js
$('#mod').modal('show');
$('#submit').on('click', function(e){
  $('.modal').modal('hide');
  console.log('Submit')
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="modal fade" id="mod" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">×</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal title</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>One fine body…</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="savebutton" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#confirm">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
  </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div><!-- /.modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="confirm" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">×</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Confirm</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>Sure</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">No</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="#mod" id="submit">Yes</button>
      </div>
    </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
  </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div><!-- /.modal -->
```

---

**<sub>With Individual Show</sub>**

```js
$('#mod').modal('show');
$('#submit').on('click', function(e){
  $('.modal').modal('hide');
  console.log('Submit')
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="modal fade" id="mod" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">×</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal title</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>One fine body…</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="savebutton" data-dismiss="modal" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#confirm">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
  </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div><!-- /.modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="confirm" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">×</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Confirm</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>Sure</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#mod">No</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="#mod" id="submit">Yes</button>
      </div>
    </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
  </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div><!-- /.modal -->
```

Comment: glad to help u mate @fireholster